# responsive layout debugging with chrome device-toolbar and media queries

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to write a login-form for my application with html and css.
in my css I'm using `@media`-queries:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    body {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    ... and some more
}
```

so in a resolution more than 767px it looks like this:
[image]

when I resize to a resolution lower than 767px it looks like this (all bigger, no box with shadow etc.):
[image]

then, I change to device view in Google Chrome with
[image]

I switch to `iPhone 5` with a resolution of `width:320px` and `height:568px`
and the result looks like this (like the one bigger than 767px):

[image]

shouldn't it look like the result lower than 767px?

Comment: Did you try to reload the page after switching to iphone 5?

Comment: Yep, I did. Still the same result.

Comment: Not sure if it could be an issue in chrome but did you add
"<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">" 
in your head?

Comment: @Traver nice! Perfect, that's the point, thanks!

Comment: I will write an answer for other users with the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the viewport tag in your head like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

More about the viewport:

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp